# How to use PowerShell to set some primitive files?

Tags: python, powershell

I've been doing "learn python the hard way" ex46 to make a skeleton of project, and I am confused about how to set the primitive files using Windows PowerShell. These are the instructions:

```
new-item -type file NAME/_init_.py
```

I typed that into PowerShell but I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't follow the instructions. You need to create the directory `NAME` first before you can create a file inside it.

Quoting from the [exercise in question](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) (emphasis mine):

> First, create the structure of your skeleton directory with these commands:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir projects
> $ cd projects/
> $ mkdir skeleton
> $ cd skeleton
> $ mkdir bin NAME tests docs
> ```

Comment: oh , does it mean that I should put _.init_.py into the NAME directory??? I had created that directory NAME but I didn't understand the instruction "new-item -type file NAME/_init_.py"

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means. Says so too. `NAME/_init_.py` is a relative path (file `_init_.py` in the subdirectory `NAME` in your current working directory).